# My Twitter replies now showing on my Tweets page

Tags: twitter

My Twitter replies are now showing on my "Tweets" Page. Before, my replies to my followers showed under "Tweets & Replies" only.  Something changed, but I do not like it.  Do you know what changed and why?

Comment: Twitter goes through redesigns all the time. So do most web applications that are around for any length of time. As for "why" they've done this particular change, only they can answer.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter re-designed their layout to remove @ replies from being included in character counts. This is so, in theory, a user can reply to an unlimited number of users, and still have room to write the full number of characters, rather than being limited to what's left after the @ replies.

I assume they did this to improve the usability of their product, as when discussions start involving many people it gets more and more difficult to carry on conversations.

So as for the particular UI change you mention, what they've done is separate the 'reply' function from the 'tweet' function, so instead of 'Tweets that are and aren't replies', there are now just tweets.